# Prolog addition

Tags: prolog

I am really stuck up with the addition predicate in prolog for  long time. Any help will greatly help me..

This is my  predicate :

`p(s(U,I), [s(A,B)|P1], T1,H(N, E), P,C) :-
          m(s(E,F),
          p(s(U,I), [s(A,B)|P1], +(C,F) ,H(N,E), P,C).`

Everything works fine except for this part :

+(C,F) always gives value like 3+2 and not like 5.

I have tried all possible methods like

`p(s(U,I), [s(A,B)|P1], T1,H(N, E), P,C) :-
          m(s(E,F)), C2 is C+F,
          p(s(U,I), [s(A,B)|P1], C2 ,H(N,E), P,C).`

But everytime it returns as someinteger+someinteger like 3+2 instead of 5.

Any help would be greatly helpful.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you add some of the use cases you've tried with the `p` predicate? It's not clear to me what all the extra arguments are for.

Comment: `H(N, E)` not is valid Prolog

Answer (score 1):

you have to use the `is/2` predicate to perform arithmetic, ie `X is 3 + 2.`. Else it's not "evaluated"!

try:

```
p(s(U, I),
  [s(A, B)|P1],
  C1,
  H(N, E),
  P,
  C) :-
    m(s(E, F)),
    C2 is F + C1,
    p(s(U, I),
      [s(A, B)|P1],
      C2,
      H(N, E),
      P,
      C).
```

predicates aren't executed if you place them in other predicate argument spots (well if we're speaking about non meta predicates as we're here). That was your problem.

Comment: I tried that but the same error occured. I used this ,

`p(s(U,I), [s(A,B)|P1], T1,H(N, E), P,C) :- m(s(E,F)), **C2 is C+F**, p(s(U,I), [s(A,B)|P1], **C2** ,H(N,E), P,C).`

But , I still get it as 3+2 instead of 5 .Any pointers?

Comment: Sorry for it.  I used the is/2 in the predicate  : `p(s(U,I), [s(A,B)|P1],C1,H(N, E), P,C) :- m(s(E,F)), p(s(U,I), [s(A,B)|P1], **C2 is F+C1** ,H(N,E), P,C).' But still I get as,`C = _h553  is  (_h532  is  0 + 5) + 5;' . It is not evaluating to 10 in arithmetic. Really confused here..

Comment: Is there any means to send code privately through stackoverflow?

Comment: I tried even that earlier, and got instantiation error as , '++Error[XSB/Runtime/P]: [Instantiation] ++Error[XSB]: [Runtime/C] Uninstantiated
 argument of evaluable function +/2
   Goal: 0 + _Var, probably as 2nd arg of is/2
Forward Continuation...
... m_#303/9
... p/6' . The instantiation error is pointing to the function m which has no errors.

Comment: @VaniJayram it means that either `F` or `C1` is a free/partially free variable. Arguments of `is/2` *must* be ground. I can't help you without more code. Your problem isn't the `is/2` predicate once you use my code, it's the fact that you don't instantiate properly your variables and that could come from any other place in your code.

Comment: Anything that I missed greatly?

Comment: @ mog could you please help get some pointers? I am just stuck up at this point for a very long time.